# notation of $2.5$ Theorem( A Course in Functional Analysis) written by John B. Conway

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces

$2.5$. Theorem. If $H$ is a Hilbert space, $K$ is a closed convex nonempty subset of $H$, and $h \in H$, then there is a unique point $k_{0} \in K$ such that
$$\lVert h-k_{0} \rVert= dist(h,K):= \inf \{ \lVert h-k \rVert: k \in K \}.$$
Part of proof. Let $d=dist(0, K)$. By definition, there is a sequence $\{k_{n} \}$ in $K$ such that $ \lVert k_{n} \rVert \to d$.

***My question is that when a sequence converges, it's certainly Cauchy and there's no need for proof anymore, so why Conway and even others tried to prove $\{k_{n}\}$ is Cauchy sequence? If proof of being a Cauchy is not needed, so the condition of being convex in the theorem not needed.***

In the following, using Parallelogram Law has proved that the sequence $\{k_{n} \}$ is Cauchy(i.e. he's proved $\lVert k_{n}-k_{m} \rVert < \varepsilon$ for $n,m > N$).

I'll continue to state the proof:Now the Parallelogram Law implies that
$$\lVert \frac{k_{n}-k_{m}}{2} \rVert^{2}= \frac{1}{2}(\lVert k_{n} \rVert^{2}+\lVert k_{m} \rVert^{2})- \lVert \frac{k_{n}+k_{m}}{2} \rVert^{2}.$$
Since $K$ is convex,$ \frac{1}{2}( k_{n}+k_{m}) \in K$. Hence $\lVert \frac{1}{2}(k_{n}+k_{m}) \rVert^{2} \ge d^{2}.$ If $ \varepsilon>0 $, choose $N$ such that for $n \ge N$, $ \lVert k_{n} \rVert^{2}<d^{2}+\frac{1}{4} \varepsilon^{2}.$ By the equation above, if $n,m>N,$ then
$$ \lVert \frac{ k_{n}-k_{m}}{2} \rVert^{2} < \frac{1}{2}(2d^{2}+\frac{1}{4} \varepsilon^{2})-d^{2}=\frac{1}{4} \varepsilon^{2}.$$
Thus $\lVert k_{n}-k_{m} \rVert < \varepsilon$ for $n,m > N$ and $k_{n}$ is Cauchy sequence. Since $H$ is complete and $K$ is closed, there is a $k_{0}$ in $K$ such that $\lVert k_{n}-k_{0} \rVert \to 0$.     (.... He has proved in the continuation of the trend :$\lVert k_{0}\rVert=d)$.

Comment: Once it is proved that $k_n$ is a Cauchy sequence then this sequence is convergent due to the completness of the space. How do you know $k_n $ is convergent otherwise ?

Comment: you know that $\| k_n \|$ is Cauchy, not $k_n$. One example that this differs is if you consider $H=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $k_n= ((-1)^n,0)$

Comment: According to the definition of the inf, there is a  sequence $\{k_{n} \}$so that it converges to $dist(0, K)$. So the  sequence $\{k_{n} \}$ converges, and as a result, is certainly Cauchy, and then using the Cauchy of the sequence and the completeness of the space has proved again the sequence is convergent.

Comment: As @alphaomega pointed out - you wrongly identify the vector k_n (an element in the given Hilbert space) with its norm (a non-negative real number).